# Refreshing all links in a paper/graph in JointJS

Tags: javascript, ports, jointjs

I am programatically adding a PORT to one of the rectangles in my graph via

```
Editor.prototype.addColumn = function(name)
{
    if(this.rects[this.model.name].attributes.inPorts == undefined)
        this.rects[this.model.name].attributes.inPorts = [];
    if(this.rects[this.model.name].attributes.inPorts.indexOf(name) < 0)
    {
        this.rects[this.model.name].attributes.inPorts.push(name);
        this.rects[this.model.name].updatePortsAttrs();
    }
}
```

While this code updates the rectangle correctly and shows the newly added port, it messes up all links attached to other ports on that rectangle. Is it possible to redraw the entire graph so that all connections are corrected, or will I have to iterate over the links in the graph and somehow update the manually ?

Thanks